# wxErlang - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets

I am very new to erlang and am trying to get my head around wxerlang but have hit a wall.  Can someone have a look at this code and tell me what is wrong.  I think it is something very obvious, but I just can't work it out.

```
-module(main).

-include_lib("include/wx.hrl").

-behavoiur(wx_object).
-export([start/0]).  %% API
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_event/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2]). %% Call Backs

-record(state, {win, action}).

-define(NEW_APP, 101).

start() ->
    wx_object:start(?MODULE, [], []).

init(Options) ->
    wx:new(Options),
    Frame = wxFrame:new(wx:null(), ?wxID_ANY, "Rails IDE", [{size,{1000,500}}]),

    MB = wxMenuBar:new(),
    wxFrame:setMenuBar(Frame,MB),
    File    = wxMenu:new([]),
    wxMenu:append(File, ?NEW_APP, "&New"),
    wxMenu:append(File, ?wxID_EXIT, "&Quit"),

    wxMenuBar:append(MB, File, "&File"),

    wxFrame:connect(Frame, command_menu_selected),

    _SB = wxFrame:createStatusBar(Frame,[]),

    MainSplitter = wxSplitterWindow:new(Frame, []),
    LeftSplitter = wxSplitterWindow:new(MainSplitter, []),
    CenterSplitter = wxSplitterWindow:new(MainSplitter, []),
    RightSplitter = wxSplitterWindow:new(MainSplitter, []),
    BottomSplitter = wxSplitterWindow:new(MainSplitter, []),

    wxSplitterWindow:setMinimumPaneSize(MainSplitter, 1),
    wxSplitterWindow:setMinimumPaneSize(LeftSplitter, 1),
    wxSplitterWindow:setMinimumPaneSize(CenterSplitter, 1),
    wxSplitterWindow:setMinimumPaneSize(RightSplitter, 1),
    wxSplitterWindow:setMinimumPaneSize(BottomSplitter, 1),

    wxFrame:show(Frame),

    State = #state{win=Frame},
    {Frame, State}.

handle_info(Msg, State) ->
    io:format("Got Info ~p~n",[Msg]),
    {noreply,State}.

handle_call(Msg, _From, State) ->
    io:format("Got Call ~p~n",[Msg]),
    {reply,ok,State}.

handle_event(#wx{id = Id,
                 event = #wxCommand{type = command_menu_selected}},
             State = #state{}) ->
    case Id of
        ?NEW_APP ->
            Panel = newAppDialog(State#state.win),
            {noreply,  State#state{action=Panel}};
        ?wxID_EXIT ->
            {stop, normal, State};
        _ ->
            {noreply, State}
    end;

handle_event(Ev,State) ->
    io:format("~p Got event ~p ~n",[?MODULE, Ev]),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    wx:destroy().


newAppDialog(Frame) ->
    Panel = wxPanel:new(Frame, []),

    %% Setup sizers
    MainSizer = wxBoxSizer:new(?wxVERTICAL),
    SubSizer = wxStaticBoxSizer:new(?wxVERTICAL, Panel, [{label, "Create a new Rails app."}]),

    Label1 = wxStaticText:new(Panel, 1, "App root"),
    DirPicker = wxDirPickerCtrl:new(Panel, 2,
                                    [{path, "/"},
                                     {style, ?wxDIRP_USE_TEXTCTRL},
                                     {message, "Select app root"}]),
    Label2 = wxStaticText:new(Panel, 3, "App name"),
    TextCtrl = wxTextCtrl:new(Panel, 4),
    Button = wxButton:new(Panel, ?wxID_OK),

    %% Add to sizers
            PickerOptions = [{border, 4},{flag, ?wxALL bor ?wxEXPAND}],
    wxSizer:add(SubSizer, Label1, PickerOptions ),
    wxSizer:add(SubSizer, DirPicker, PickerOptions ),
    wxSizer:add(SubSizer, Label2, PickerOptions ),
    wxSizer:add(SubSizer, TextCtrl, PickerOptions),
    wxSizer:add(SubSizer, Button, PickerOptions),

    SizerOptions  = [{flag, ?wxEXPAND}],
    wxSizer:add(MainSizer, SubSizer, SizerOptions),

    wxWindow:connect(Panel, command_button_clicked),
    wxPanel:setSizer(Panel, MainSizer),
    wxSizer:layout(MainSizer),
    Panel.
```

Comment: It might help to have the actual error you get.

Comment: You might also want to try to cut the code down to a smaller example that exhibits the same problem. Besides making it easier for others to answer you, it's a good technique for debugging yourself; once you've eliminated everything extraneous, the problem in the remaining code may become more obvious.

Comment: My problem lies in handle_event/3 in the case of ?NEW_APP
newAppDialog is run as a new process and exits, but nothing is displyed in the frame.  The main process is still running but werl drops back to the command line.

I am confused maybe I have jumped in to far and will take alook at the OTP stuff first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get a compilation error?

Change the include_lib line to

```
-include_lib("wx/include/wx.hrl").
```

With that change it compiles and I get a blank window when it is run (I'm using erl 5.7.2 on Mac OS X). Is that what you expect?

If you're new to Erlang it's probably easier to start with something more straightforward. It's not too difficult to understand the wx_object man page but only once you've got a handle on OTP and have written a couple of test servers first in my humble opinion. Once you're at that point overlaying how wx works on top of that is a more simple step. Doing both at the same time will be more of a challenge, but your mileage may vary of course...!

Comment: I went through the spawnlink tutorials and have a much better understanding of erlang now, although I obviously have much further to go, but thanks for the advice.

http://spawnlink.com/articles/tag/erlybank/

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I notice that

-behaviour(wx_object).

is spelled wrong.  (You have behavoiur(wx_object).